# OpenCV CMake Error

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv, opencv2, libopencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using OpenCV without issue for months, but today when I catkin_make my workspace I now get the error:

> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'clam_vision'
> -- ==> add_subdirectory(clam_vision) CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> configuration file for package
> vision_opencv.
>
> Set vision_opencv_DIR to the
> directory containing a CMake
> configuration   file for
> vision_opencv.  The file will have one
> of the following names:
>
> ```
> vision_opencvConfig.cmake
> vision_opencv-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> clam_vision/CMakeLists.txt:7
> (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:71
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> configuration file for package
> opencv2.
>
> Set opencv2_DIR to the directory
> containing a CMake configuration file
> for   opencv2.  The file will have one
> of the following names:
>
> ```
> opencv2Config.cmake
> opencv2-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> clam_vision/CMakeLists.txt:7
> (find_package)

I have tried reinstalling ros-groovy-vision-opencv and ros-groovy-opencv2. Searching my computer I found lots of files named *opencv*.cmake in different locations.

I have made no changes except updating ROS, and everything seems to be installed and working correctly, so I do not understand what the issue is.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56686/opencv-cmake-error/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-03-04**:
I'm also using OpenCV in ROS Groovy and I need to use the cvblob library. I have the same linking error while compiling, just for the cvblob lib can not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Vincent Rabaud helped me through this issue via Email:

> Ok, so vision_opencv is a stack so you
> cannot depend on it/find_package it:
> you have to depend/find_package any of
> its packages (cv_bridge ...).
>
> opencv2 is not a ROS package so you
> cannot find_package it through catkin.
> You need to find_package it as any
> user would do: find_package(OpenCV).
> I'll update the wiki for that.

So now in my package.xml I have:

```
  <build_depend>image_geometry</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>OpenCV</build_depend>
```

And in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cv_bridge image_geometry ...)
...
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
...
add_executable(calibrate_kinect_checkerboard
  src/detect_calibration_pattern.cpp
  src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp
  )
target_link_libraries(calibrate_kinect_checkerboard ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-10-07**:
I am facing the same problem, but this explanation seems to be a little more complicated for a beginner like me, can you please explain in a little easy way.
Thanking you.

**Comment by [GeneralSpoonFul](https://answers.ros.org/users/8371/generalspoonful/) on 2014-01-08**:
I have the same problem and I'm still facing the same problem even if I added the lines Dave Coleman said to in the package and CMakeLists files... I still can't find the cv_bridge package when using catkin_make.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have something like this in your CMakeList.txt to link OpenCV with your pkg:

```
include_directories(include  
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 /home/elod/opencv/cmake/
) 
 ...
add_executable(bagDetect src/main.cpp)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(bagDetect ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I'm working with ROS Groovy therefore my package.xml has this rows to:

```
<build_depend>OpenCV</build_depend>
<run_depend>cvBlob</run_depend>
```

If you build it with `make VERBOSE=1`, than ur able to check the linked libraries.

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-03-04**:
Thanks for the answer, that's about what I did after Vincent helped me. Also, I'm pretty sure having "/home/elod/opencv/cmake/" hard coded into your CMakeLists is bad practice.